# Using two different versions of the same node dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to include two versions of the same dependency in nodejs package.json?

For testing purposes, I need to use two versions of socket.io (one to expose a socket in the latest version and one to simulate a dependency server using an old release).

`{
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "~0.9.0",
    "socket.io": "~1.2.0"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can first fork socket.io 0.9 on github:
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/0.9

To create https://github.com/youaccount/socket.io/tree/0.9

Then use this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "oldsocket.io": "git+ssh://git@github.youaccount/socket.io.git#0.9",
    "socket.io": "~1.2.0"
}
```

Edit the package.json and rename the `name` attribute to `oldsocket.io`

And you can now require `socket.io` or `oldsocket.io`